# CPLEX java - Equality constraints for multidimensional arrays

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, cplex

I am solving a Linear Programming using CPLEX in Java. I have a binary decision variable defined as

```
IloNumVar[] xd = new IloNumVar[Tend];
```

where Tend is the time. The decision variable is subject to the constraint that the sum over time of xd must be equal a given integer C_d, which was implemented as:

```
cplex.addEq(cplex.sum(xd), C_d);
```

So far everything was working.

The problem I am having is that now I am trying to generalize the number of decision variables using a multidimensional array:

```
IloNumVar[][] xd = new IloNumVar[Tend][count_d];
```

but I still need to impose the constraint that the sum of each decision variable over time must be equal to a constant. I tried with this:

```
IloNumVar[] Sum_d   = new IloNumVar[Tend];
IloNumVar[]  Sum_D  = new IloNumVar[1];
for(int j=0;j<count_d;j++){
    for (int i = 1; i<Tend; i++){
        cplex.addEq(Sum_d[i],cplex.sum(Sum_d[i-1],xd[i][j])); 
        }
    cplex.addEq(Sum_d[Tend],Sum_D);
    cplex.addEq(Sum_D,C_d);
    }
```

but I get the following errors:
Multiple markers at this line

- The method addEq(IloNumExpr, double) in the type IloCplexModeler is not applicable for the arguments (IloNumVar, IloNumVar[])
- The method addEq(IloNumExpr, double) in the type IloCplexModeler is not applicable for the arguments (IloNumVar[], int)

I am not quite sure what is the proper way to include the equivalent constraint in the problem definition.

Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to non-respect of the `addEq` overloads.

In all of the six overloads of the `addEq` [function](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.4.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refjavacplex/html/ilog/concert/IloModeler.html) the RHS of the equation you're adding to your model is to be an integer. Its always a `double` or another `IloNumExpr`.

Therefore, you only need to declare:

`double C_d`

One is glad to be of service!